# How to add Google Analytics Tracking ID to GitHub Pages

Tags: github, google-analytics, github-pages

Could be a simple question but I am full of doubts right now about adding **Google Analytics Tracking ID** to **GitHub page**.

I am using GitHub automatic page generator to create my GitHub page but it asks for "Google Analytics Tracking ID". I tried to sign up with Google Analytics but there on it asks for website URL.

Now what I am supposed to do?

One more ques: can we add Google Analytics Tracking ID later on after GitHub Page has been created?

Comment: Quite a few suggested approaches but I can't get/confirm any of them working yet. I'm hoping it will just start working in 24 hours or so.

Comment: /Headdesk. I had my Brave browser blocking trackers on my sites. It was working the whole time. Also a confusing thing for me was the (semi) recent move from ga (google analytics) to gtag (google tag). Apparently you only need the gtag() stuff now, no longer the ga() stuff. Fun. These links helped me diagnose my problem: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk and https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-vs-google-analytics/

Comment: @ChrisEmerson that's some useful update :)

Comment: I had similar issues of my visits not registering, turns out AdBlock was responsible for them.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

**Update**: Added steps descriptions for others

Solved it:
had to include `username.github.io` (link that I want to track) in Google Analytics website section.

you can check GitHub help page [here](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/user/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator)

---

[image]

---

After that I was provided with an Tracker ID.

---

**Note:** You can easily change or add more websites on Google Analytics page from your Google Analytics admin panel.

---

**Update 2: - Adding Google Analytics Tracking ID to Already created Github pages** (As requested by [@avi-aryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2295672/avi-aryan) )

1. Browse to your github pages branch - which would be something like - 
   ( https://github.com/**YourUserName**/**YourRepository**/tree/gh-pages )
2. Then edit `index.html` from listed files
3. Now in within `HEAD` tag of `index.html` - paste your Google Analytics Tracking ID Script ( if have already signed up for Google analytics then you can browse it under **admin** and then **tracking info** tab )

Comment: @Bingo , I currently use `<iframe>` to include a footer.html in every page of my website. I have added the `<script>` to it's `<head>` tag. It doesn't seems that it is working. I will  try your solution and report back.

Comment: @AviAryan you will have to add tracking script in main file as well like `index.html` and `iframe html` - you will have to add script in both

Comment: I have added them, however Google analytics say the Tracking is not installed. My page as specified in G-Analytics is `http://avi-aryan.github.io`

Comment: @AviAryan your files seems to be correct, have you added `avi-aryan.github.io/` as website url in Google analytics `profile setting` under admin section

Comment: @Bingo No, but `avi-aryan.github.io`  Does a `/` make a difference.

Comment: @AviAryan Although I think that shouldn't make any difference but surprisingly all my sites are listed there on with `/` at the end. And just for info, you can try `statcounter.com` as well it pretty much simple and is quiet fast as compared google analytics in updating results

Comment: @Bingo G.Analytics is working now. I can see the stats. It looks it takes 24 hrs to be activated.  Thanks for your help and I wanna confirm `/` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @AviAryan ohh congrats, and confirmation about `/` - will have to try it out by changing the website listing

Comment: @Bingo, have you tried `statcounter.com`.  I get the error `Double check your website address below and try again.` when I use `http://avi-aryan.github.io`

Comment: @AviAryan Yeah I have been using `statcounter.com`. try with `/` in the end and BTW did you paste the `statcounter script` in your html page?

Comment: @Bingo Again, i got it working, don't really know what different I did as I was doing hit and trials again and again until I got something in favour.  Thanks, now I will compare the two and think on what I should use.

Comment: @AviAryan ohh well go ahead, BTW I am using both simultaneously as one is fast (statcounter) and other one gives sort of detailed stats(Google Analytics)

Comment: Bitdeli provides a free badge that you can add to your READMEs in GitHub. It will give you access to the full request logs, which allows you to analyze who has been viewing your repositories.

Comment: @OhadR No idea why you commented about this here out of no where but thumbs up for `bitdeli` - its nice :) and thanks for letting me know abt that

Comment: because unfortunately your suggestion did not work for me, so I had to keep searching for another way...

Comment: @OhadR ohh sorry for that if it didn't helped u

Comment: FYI: I used the same logic for editing `index.html` for adding twitter's conversion tracking too. Thanks!

Comment: It'd be great to see an updated answer to this question.  It seems that the standard code snippet that GA provides just does not successfully install or track page views if creating a custom page on a gh-pages branch.

Comment: @sealocal thanks for the uspdate. Let me check on the same and then will update the answer

Comment: I just tried this on a github page, adding the google analytical script in head of index.html, but it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone confirm this answer is still the correct solution?

Comment: @sc28 just verified on my github pages and yeah I can see stats from google analytics. Are you getting error ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking. All I see is in Google analytics the status remains "No data received in past 48 hours.". I also tried the "Send test traffic", which correctly opens the page. I added the script snippet at the end of the <head> section. Is that really the right place?

Comment: @sc28 when did you put analytics on your page? google usually updates the dashboard after quite a while

Comment: About an hour ago. I assumed the update would be fairly quick, given they warn that "the update can take up to 30 seconds", but maybe I should still wait a few hours after copying the analytics script for the first time?

Comment: @sc28 no it usually takes a day or two.. check after a day or two

Comment: This is the simplest answer, and worked for me in a few minutes.

Comment: @jimh glad it helped you :)

Comment: is it safe to have your google analytics tracking ID public?

Comment: @exexzian The github help article page link given in the answer is broken.

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator

The new link page is here...

https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/user/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator

Comment: @Kharthigeyan thanks for the update - updated the link

Comment: What about when you need to get analytics for a GitHub Page which is a sub-folder? Something like `https://username.github.io/my-project/`.

Comment: @exexzian how can I track a multiple pages (of the same website)?

Answer (score 94):

For anyone interested, if you are using Jekyll with GitHub pages, I just wrote a post showing how to correctly [add Google Analytics Tracking ID to Jekyll](https://desiredpersona.com/google-analytics-jekyll/).

1. You will find your Universal Analytics tracking code under Admin > Property > Tracking Info > Tracking Code.
2. Create a new file called `analytics.html` in the `_includes` folder found in your Jekyll website’s directory.
3. Add Google Analytics Tracking ID code to `analytics.html`.
4. Finally, open `_layouts/head.html`, and add `{% include analytics.html %}` just before the end `</head>` tag. Google recommends this placement to track all of the pages on your website correctly.

Comment: Thank you, great post. It's worth noting that within GitHub Pages it is set `jekyll.environment == 'production'` automatically (https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1219), while the Jekyll default environment is `'development'`

Comment: I had `_layouts/default.html`, but it worked just fine (I'm not familiar with Jekyll)

Comment: Alternatively, just copy it directly into `head.html`

Comment: Is this out of date? Google Analytics now uses the 'Google tag' instead of the Global Site Tag.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using the minima template provide by Jekyll then -

1. Add `google_analytics: UA-xxxxxxxx-x` to your _config.yml
2. Create a file _includes/google-analytics.html and add the google analytics js code in it.

Replace

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
```

with

```
ga('create', '{{ site.google_analytics }}', 'auto');
```

and you are set!

The google analytics code will now display if your site is built in production environment. For reference see the template's source code here - https://github.com/jekyll/minima

You can follow the same approach if you are using a different template by referencing the template's source code and replacing the corresponding files.

Comment: Step 2 is actually not needed. Check the documentation at https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal

Comment: As of April 2022, the above theme has more directions re: Google Analytics and using GA's newer scripts: https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal/tree/814b8723af0aa0ada9b5784da6b73d862bb74150#customizing-google-analytics-code

Answer (score 16):

Is better to use GA-Beacon for that.  GA-Beacon can track all your GitHub repo, even if the visited link isn't an html document.

Please check:  https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon

Comment: It works but all my real time data records it came from Ashburn VA. Even when i visit the page locally...very far from VA.

Comment: @jtlindsey - Is there any chance that your image/pixel is being cached at a CDN in Ashburn VA?

Comment: @pulkitsinghal I'm not entirely sure, That post was almost a month ago and I had been using it for a few weeks and data was always Ashburn VA. Looking back at my data now, the data shows location not set for real-time but there are queries from all over the world in history so I'm not sure where the error is. I will likely remove it because the data isn't correct.

Answer (score 9):

Adding analytics via **_config.yml**.

All GitHub themes ([supported themes](https://pages.github.com/themes/)) natively support google analytics.
You just have to provide a tracking code (UA-XXXXXXXXX-X).

Google analytics comes in two flavours - **Google analytics 4** (GA4), and **Universal analytics**. You will have to use the latter for this. **GA4 will not work** <sup>#</sup>.

1. Create a new Universal google analytics property (and **not GA4 property**). By default the tracking property you create will be of type GA4. You will have to select "Create a Universal Analytics property" for the property to be universal.
   Once a GA4 property is created it cannot be converted to Universal property. You can only do this while creating a new property.

[image: Show advanced options]

1.1 Turn Universal analytics on in the advanced options.

[image: Create a Universal Analytics property]

1.2 Configure Universal analytics options.

[image: Universal analytics options]

1.3 Copy the tracking ID for this newly created property.

[image: Tracking ID]

2. Add this tracking ID to your gh-pages sites's _config.yml.

   google_analytics: UA-XXXXXXXXX-X

The following is from [modernist's readme](https://github.com/pages-themes/modernist) - the theme I was using for my site.

[image: modernist theme readme]

3. Commit and Push the changes to github, and after few minutes navigate to your site's URL.
4. Verify that everything went fine.

If you search the source code now for the tracing ID, you will be able to find it.
Google analytics dashboard too will start showing activity.

[image: Tracking code in site's source]

The above steps show how to add google analytics to an existing gh-pages site. You can use the same code while creating a new gh-pages site too. Although it seems automatic page generator no longer exists - [Can't locate "automatic page generator" button in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248716/cant-locate-automatic-page-generator-button-in-github/41249143)

*# Maybe there is a way to use GA4 natively by configuring _config.yml. I wasn't able to do that, and had to resort to universal analytics.*

**Reference(s)**

https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/downgrade-from-google-analytics-4-to-universal-analytics/

Comment: In 1.2, is it okay to choose 'Create both a Google Analytics 4 and a Universal Analytics property' or should we create a Universal Analytics property only?

Comment: @codesnerd I went for universal analytics only (although I just noticed that the pic I uploaded shows radio button for both selected). Both might work, as long as you get ID of the form `UA-XXXXXXXXX-X`. The GA4 ID has a different format.

Answer (score 6):

You can add Google Analytics to a Jekyll site the same way you would any other site.

First, after setting up your Google Analytics account, navigate to the admin tab.

[image: navbar]

Next, under the accounts panel, on the left, click: `Create New Account`.

[image: add account]

In Google Analytics, an account represents a set of pages that you would like to track. Set up the website's account as desired.

After your account has been created you will be sent to a page which tells you your `Tracking ID` and has a JavaScript snippet for you to put on the pages you would like to track. Simply put this snippet in all the pages you would like to track. Or, if you use a default layout put this snippet somewhere in it.

By the way, since you are hosting on GitHub Pages you don't need Google Analytics unless you want very detailed analytics. [If all you care about is page views GitHub has this.](https://github.com/blog/1672-introducing-github-traffic-analytics)

Comment: I'm pretty use that GitHub's tracking is only for traffic onto the GitHub repository itself (including source code). My GitHub Pages site repo only shows traffic to GitHub URLs.

Answer (score 6):

I use the README.md file as a source for my GitHub personal page. I also use one of the GitHub supported themes 'cayman'. No more files is required in the repository apart from _config.yml (unless you want to modify your supported theme).

To add Google Analytics, I just followed the advice in the 'cayman' repository (https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman):

Cayman will respect the following variables, if set in your site's _config.yml:

google_analytics: [Your Google Analytics tracking ID]

Full stop! Anything else! Everything works on the side of Google Analytics!
It may be a viable option for those who look for a quick set up of GitHub Pages with Google Analytics.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using an automatically generated github page from your github README.md I found this to be the easiest way:
Just edit your _config.yml to look like this (with your own google analytics UA id):

```
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman
title: My Site
description: My site description
url: https://example.com
author: MyName
plugins:
  - jekyll-seo-tag
google_analytics: UA-xxx
```

Then add a new file to your repository root named Gemfile with this content:

```
source "https://rubygems.org”
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'
```

Then wait a bit and refresh your github page and show page source code. Verify that the SEO plugin has inserted your analytics java script.
More info here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag

From the installation instruction, I didn't have to add the {% seo %} in the html, luckily, because I have no html. Github seems to have thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

With me, I was unable to configure Google Analytics 4 (prev Web+App) via adding google_analytics: UA-xxxxxxxx-x to your _config.yml as mentioned previously in one of the answers.

So I had to put the js recommended by the Google Analytics in the .md file.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

Anything you put in the script tag in .md will not be rendered.

Comment: I downgraded from google analytics 4 to universal analytics for the same reason. Universal Analytics gives tracking code of the form UA-xxxxxxxxx-x, GA4 doesn't. https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/downgrade-from-google-analytics-4-to-universal-analytics/

Answer (score 1):

**Include a Global site tag in the html output <head>**

Once you setup a Google Analytics account, detailed instructions are included under the "Data Streams" tab- select your data source, and then "Tagging instructions" for *Global site tag(gtag.js)*

***Global site tag***

the script will look something like this (with id replaced by XXXXXXXXXXX in my example):

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

Save the html script within a file in your Project directory (e.g. as "GA_script.html")

***Add html file to the header***

in the Rmarkdown YAML, add the reference to your specific script ([see ref here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/include-html.html)):

```
output:
  html_document:
    includes: 
      in_header: GA_script.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Jekyll Minima. See these GitHub issues for reference:

- [feat: Support GA4 - Google Analytics 4 properties](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues/555)
- [Google Analytics data not received](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues/561)

Answer (score 0):

Set google_analytics at _config.yml with tracing-id started with UA- rather than G-,tracing-id like G-xxxx is of Google Analytics 4. and Jekyll does not support Google Analytics 4.

Use

```
google_analytics: UA-xxxxxx-x
```

Do not use

```
google_analytics: G-xxxxxx
```

However,Google Analytics(Universal Analytics) is no longer supported by Google until 2023.7.1.