# How to get download statistics/analytics from gh-pages for DRAT archives

Tags: r, github, google-analytics, github-pages, drat

**Some background:**

The R language community has a big packages repository called *CRAN*. 
With the [***drat*** package](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat) it is easy to host private CRAN-like repositories. There are many organizations which hosts their R packages using the ***drat*** package and a `gh-pages` branch. ***Drat*** simply creates a directory structure which is recognized by the R command `install.packages()`. There is no `index.html` file in the repository structure.

**My question is then:**

How can one gather per-file download statistics from these `gh-pages`? 
I've found the "[How to add Google Analytics Tracking ID to GitHub Pages](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/17207458/how-to-add-google-analytics-tracking-id-to-github-pages)" question but it requires an `index.html`, so it cannot be used here.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Is this supported by GitHub at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't be done. You can track HTML page delivery from gh-pages because HTML pages can run the Google Analytics Javascript. But a download is a download and doesn't run any scripts.