# How can I track github pages with Google analytics 4 - measurement ID?

Tags: github, github-pages, mkdocs, google-analytics-4

I have a repo with README.md as main page. This repo uses mkdocs for generating static site. Also, added Google Analaytics measurement ID to the mkdocs.yml for tracking the traffic on the static site.
But my current requirement is to track the github pages on repo. I am aware of github insights feature where we can get the metrics. But would need more details for every github page.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2):

You already use Google Analytics to track your GitHub Pages website, but you want it to track your repo also, right?

In that case, it is not possible, because differently from your website, even if you do own the repo, you do not own it's page, GitHub does. And you probably added some HTML to track your website, but you can't change your repo's HTML. This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140178/how-to-add-google-analytics-to-github-respository).

Now, if I misunderstood and what you want is to track your GitHub Pages website, then [yes, you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207458/how-to-add-google-analytics-tracking-id-to-github-pages)