# Can't locate "automatic page generator" button in Github

Tags: github

I'm not able to find the "automatic page generator button" under a repository's setting page. Could someone please let me know where I can find the button? Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at https://pages.github.com/ - that's got all the info about Github Pages now.

Comment: Things have changed. A more recent documentation is at → [pages.github.com](https://pages.github.com/)

Comment: See an answer here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102324/github-pages-i-cannot-access-automatic-page-generator

Comment: Github's overview video on pages.github.com still includes using the "Launch automatic page generator button". They really need to change that.

Comment: from the webapps.SE you can see  this feature has been removed. the idea of doing this in my case was to customize the built in jekyll themes. So I wanted to generate the site and change the css. Since it's no more I just built it locally with  jekyll and got running quickly using the official docker image.

Comment: 2022: [no more theme picker either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73454724/6309).

Answer (score 16):

There is no automatic page generator button in GitHub anymore, I am not able to find it in any of my repos. GitHub now uses Jekyll to make the pages.

Instead, you can do the following to create a GitHub webpage:
Go to `github.com/YOUR_REPO_NAME/settings/` then scroll down to the GitHub Pages section and select the "Choose a theme" button. Then choose a theme and select the green "Chose theme" button. Now create an `index.html` in the `master` branch and create your page there.

Comment: so we _have_ to upload .html files, and there is no way to upload markdown files and have github apply the selected style?

Comment: You can now go back to the same place and press the `Choose theme` button, and it will work the exact same way it used to!    You just can't make a gh-pages branch anymore.

Comment: The video at https://pages.github.com/ still mentions the automatic page generator

Comment: This is probably because the video is older, and GitHub has not had time to update it.

Comment: September 2017 and the same video is still there.  Not a great introduction for the new GitHub Pages users that it is aimed at.

Comment: If you choose a *Jekyll* **theme** as outlined in the GitHub Pages [guide](https://pages.github.com/) it automatically creates the associated **index** and other files to properly display *.md* *markdown* files as a site.

Comment: 2020 and the video is still not updated. XD