# I am not finding "Launch Automatic Page Generator"

Tags: github-pages

I am not finding "Launch Automatic Page Generator" in setting option of github(version 2.26.0.windows.1) how to get it

Comment: As [GitHub Enterprise](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator) was discontinued on March 27, 2019. alternative solution [Setting up a GitHub Pages site with Jekyll](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll)

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic page generator button in GitHub anymore, I am not able to find it in any of my repos. GitHub now uses Jekyll to make the pages.

Instead, you can do the following to create a GitHub webpage: Go to github.com/YOUR_REPO_NAME/settings/ then scroll down to the GitHub Pages section and select the "Choose a theme" button. Then choose a theme and select the green "Chose theme" button. Now create an index.html in the master branch and create your page there.

Answer (score 0):

Even the "Choose a theme" button might disappear, from Aug. 2022:

> ### [GitHub Pages: Deprecating the theme picker](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-22-github-pages-deprecating-the-theme-picker/)
>
> Today (Aug. 22, 2022), we are deprecating the theme picker we introduced in [2012 for GitHub Pages](https://github.blog/2012-04-02-instantly-beautiful-project-pages/).
>
> While this experience allowed users to preview a theme in the user interface, we are doing this to increase the security of github.com.
>
> You can of course continue to use any [Jekyll theme](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/) you want with Pages, and publish beautiful sites with a [small configuration change](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll).