# Finding the number of views of a website hosted on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, web, github-pages

I have built myself a website with GitHub Pages but it is possible to tell how many visitors have been there?

I know there is the traffic tab in my repository, does this also show me the amount of views on my site as well as the repository itself?   If not how can I do it?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask similar question there instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to view the number of visitors to a GitHub pages site through GitHub itself. To get this functionality you would have to add a third party analytics tool such as [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) or [Plausible](https://plausible.io/) to your website.