# Could I create a .log file for my personal Github website to tracking who is click my page?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a website written by js-css-html and some php. I have uploaded all the files to the github and it is activively working. As you know, it is a **web-page** which you can access it via a link.

What I'm trying to do is to see **who click to my website**. In my search I find that **log files** do this what I want. How can add log file to **keep tracking** who is click my web-page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GitHub page does have analytics:

- either natively through [Traffic page](https://github.blog/2014-01-07-introducing-github-traffic-analytics/),
- or through third-party tools, like [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) (with [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601997/6309) or a [pixel tracked](https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon))