# GitHub Pages and Google Analytics set up with GA4

Tags: google-analytics, jekyll, github-pages

I'm currently struggling to find a way to set up Google Analytics for a GitHub Pages website. There are ways given on the internet but they all use the old Universal Analytics (UA) property and not the new GA4 property. I'm using jekyll and a README page on my GitHub Pages.

Tried the old methods but non worked. For example I tried [How to add Google Analytics Tracking ID to GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207458/how-to-add-google-analytics-tracking-id-to-github-pages). But with the measurement id.